# How to create empty collection in Firestore Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

How can I create an empty collection in Firestore (Swift)? i want to do that when I create DB users after I registrate them, because on my main screen it tries to fetch from that collection that doesn't exists and I get a crash

Comment: Answer below. But note that it should be possible to handle the absence of documents in the code. If you're having trouble with the app crashing with code you wrote for this use-case, show the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Querying a non-existent collection shouldn't cause an application to crash.  It should just yield 0 results.

Comment: @DougStevenson yea i know that but somewhere in my app were a problem but now its working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way you can create an empty collection in Cloud Firestore. To solve this, you should create at least one document within that collection. In this way, that particular collection will start to exist.

If you create a collection in the Firebase Console containing one document, the collection is created automatically for you. This is also happening if you try to delete the last document in a collection, that particular collection will be automatically deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Collections are automatically created when you write a document to them. There is no way to create a collection without a document in it.