# Creating new collection in cloud firestore inside my code

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I was just wondering if there is any way to automatically put a new sub collection in the firestore?

Basically my data structure is the main collection 'matches' and then I wanted to create subcollections with names of the seasons such as 's2018', 's2019' etc...

So instead of putting it all manually in the console. I wanted to create a button to add a new season on the website. I know it's easy to create a new document inside the collection but is there any way or code like addCollection() that I can use in my react application?

Here is how my data is structured:

Matches(main collection) -> seasons(several sub collections) -> match(document with the result of the match and teams)

I'm looking for a code such as

```
db.collection.addCollection()
```

or something in this particular type to create a new collection after filling up details and pressing the submit button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A collection is automatically created when you first write a document to it. There is no need to separate pre-create them.

Also see:

- [How to create collection in Cloud Firestore from Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47871288/how-to-create-collection-in-cloud-firestore-from-javascript)
- [How to create a Collection in Firestore with node.js code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46623759/how-to-create-a-collection-in-firestore-with-node-js-code)
- [How to create empty collection in Firestore Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55728065/how-to-create-empty-collection-in-firestore-swift)